# When will #hyperledger-composer be supported for Ubuntu bionic (64bit v18.04)?

Tags: ubuntu, hyperledger-composer

Whe I attempted install, I got an error message stating that Ubuntu bionic is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow [these instructions](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/prereqs.html) to install pre-requisites